Angular 17: An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected token '??='
I am using Angular 17 project. I am using node version manager (nvm) to manage the node versions. When I run ng serve in project directory, I get the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
at Object. Any help is appreciated.

I am not using '??=' token in my code. I have tried to search for this issue but couldn't find any similar question. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Edit:

I did not know the name of this operator ??= in Angular
The error is coming from Angular library file on running ng serve. So there is no piece of code that I can attach here


The error was due to node version incompatible with the angular version being used. Fixing the version of node and then running ng serve resolved the error.
If managing multiple node versions for different projects using nvm, please make sure to switch to the correct version of node using the command nvm use <<node version>>, then try ng serve again
